# Python - how to receive data and serve it as a websocket server?

Tags: python, websocket

I'm facing a problem with a python application i'm trying to build: basically i have a script that receives simple json data from a Redis PUBSUB connection, and i would like to serve this data to client as a websocket server. So basically, every time i receive a message from the redis connection, that message must be sent to clients using websockets.

Here is my basic code:

The part where i receive data from the redis pubsub connection:

```
import json
import redis

redis_url = 'MY-URL'
channel = 'test'

connection = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(redis_url, decode_responses=True)

pubsub = connection.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=False)
pubsub.subscribe(channel)


for item in pubsub.listen():
    message = item['data']

    if type(message) != int:
        message = json.loads(message)
        print(message)
```

And here is a simple websocket server, i'm using `websockets`:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def main(websocket, path):
    while True:
        await websockets.send('Some data')

start_server = websockets.serve(main, "localhost", 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

I'm missing the way to merge this two parts of code. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Solution 1

In this example for each new `websocket` connection request we are registering new listener

```py
import json
import redis
import asyncio
import websockets

redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
channel = 'test'

connection = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(redis_url, decode_responses=True)

pubsub = connection.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=False)
pubsub.subscribe(channel)

async def main(websocket, path):
    for item in pubsub.listen():
        message = item['data']

        if type(message) != int:
            message = json.loads(message)
            print(message)
            await websocket.send(message)

start_server = websockets.serve(main, "localhost", 8765)

print("Started")
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

#### Solution 2

Here we have used single listerer to send events to multiple clients which register through websocket and send messages to opened websocket connection

```py
import json
import redis
import gevent
from flask import Flask
from flask_sockets import Sockets

redis_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
channel = 'test'

connection = redis.StrictRedis.from_url(redis_url, decode_responses=True)

class PubSubListener(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []
        self.pubsub = connection.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=False)
        self.pubsub.subscribe(**{channel: self.handler})
        self.thread = self.pubsub.run_in_thread(sleep_time=0.001)

    def register(self, client):
        self.clients.append(client)

    def handler(self, message):
        _message = message['data']

        if type(_message) != int:
            self.send(_message)

    def send(self, data):
        for client in self.clients:
            try:
                client.send(data)
            except Exception:
                self.clients.remove(client)

pslistener = PubSubListener()

app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/echo')
def echo_socket(ws):
    pslistener.register(ws)

    while not ws.closed:
        gevent.sleep(0.1)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from gevent import pywsgi
    from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler
    print("Started")
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: @JayK23 I did'nt test them because i don't have setup l will update you when i update my answer with working code.